# dynamic load function for ng-click with evel

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-click

You will find plunder of this here : [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KDreNM6xDcgIbReJOSEK)

UI is like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/7H1b3.png

I have ng-repeat with which I want to create ng-click in directive template.
Template name as mainTemplate.html and its code is below code:

```
<form class="class">
  <p>Inside directive</p>

<div ng-repeat='mainJson in mainJsonData'>
    <div class="{{mainJson.divClass}}">
        <input ng-model="mainJson[mainJson.inputNgModel]" type="{{mainJson.inputType}}" class="{{mainJson.inputClass}}" placeholder="{{mainJson.placeHolder}}" maxlength='{{mainJson.inputMaxLength}}' value="{{mainJson.value}}" ng-click="mainJson[mainJson.ngClick]()"/>
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>
</form>
```

Directive:

```
add.directive('testData', function() {
return {
    templateUrl: 'template/mainTemplate.html',
    controller: function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('json/mainUi.json').success(function(response) {
            $scope.mainJsonData = response;
        });
    }
 };
});
```

And json is with which i am trying to create directive :

```
[
{
 "divClass":"form-group",
 "inputType":"text",
 "inputClass":"form-control",
 "inputNgModel":"mobile",
 "inputMaxLength":"10",
 "placeHolder":"mobile"
},
{   
 "divClass":"form-group",
 "inputType":"button",
 "inputClass":"btn btn-success",
 "ngClick":"addData",
 "value":"Save",
 "ngClickData":"name, city, mobile"
}
]
```

and I am looking for ng-click as :

```
ng-click="addData(name, city, mobile)
```

which should work with ng-model as ng-model also get created same from

Comment: Sorry, Idk if I got it, do you want receive the "function" in the json response? Its not possible to pass a function in the json..

Comment: I want to grab value of ng-model which generate dynamically in ng-repeat. so that I am able to pass that value to controller using ng-click

Comment: You can use the same variable name in the ng-click like this:`ng-click="myFunction(mainJson[mainJson.inputNgModel])"`. And in the function you will receive the variable value

Comment: I have attached image which help you to understand better. Basically I am create this UI using ng-repeat and i want to pass value of all 3 input field to controller on save click. And i am appending a value to ng-model using ng-model = mainJson[mainJson.inputNgModel], since it generate using ng-repeat.

Comment: And i have also create plunker of this : https://plnkr.co/edit/KDreNM6xDcgIbReJOSEK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string in a array.

Like the example: https://plnkr.co/edit/6RHVKKhWQC4r3JsBAPEJ?p=preview

I put hard coded what you have, insted the `name|city|mobile` your is `mainJson[mainJson.inputNgModel]`.

**UPDATE**

Its works, but idk if its good do what you are doing, the maintence will be very dificulty.

The working version based on yours: https://plnkr.co/edit/opDKuIYkDmmR7Nk4xZeP?p=preview

Comment: No, it is not working as UI is getting generate from JSON data. I have create plunker for reference  : plnkr.co/edit/KDreNM6xDcgIbReJOSEK